# How many projects are needed to setup an Unit test

Tags: c++, eclipse, unit-testing, boost

**Direct question:** Must I have two project in my workspace to test one application? One for the application and another for the unit test. Or can I have only one project all together?

**Question description:** Nowadays I am programming a little application in Eclipse C++ with MinGW and I want to test it with Boost Test library and C/C++ Unit. I have read the manual and tutorial and in they say that Boost creates a main function. This means that I must have 2 different projects (one the app and another for the tests). But in this case, when I made a change in the code, I have to do it twice (in both projects). It looks very annoying, so I tough that maybe I am wrong and there is a way to use the source code from the application directly in the unit tests maybe with a unique project or with some specific configuration for the Unit Test project.

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I always use 1 project for each library + 1 project for each executable + 1 or more projects for my unit tests. Yes like the one answer says you can put your unit tests in your main executable and use command line switches to activate the unit tests however I too believe this is not best. Do you want your users to be able execute unit tests or will you have some mechanism to disable them when you ship your application.

Answer (score 3):

First, you can put all your tests in the same project as the code, but this may not be the best plan. Your main function would have to take arguments to switch between test and actual behaviour.

I often end up with three projects: A library, my main exe and the test project.
You could just add the same cpp files to the tests and the main exe if you don't want to make a third project, but in the long run making a third library project may be sensible.

Second, you can build boost test so that you can write your own main if you want. If you are changing identical code twice this is asking for trouble. If you are trying to maintain a copy of the code in order to test it you are going to make a mistake. Don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

What you've described is a problem that's really a disaster waiting to happen.  Your unit tests need to be testing your application's code, not a copy of your application's code.  But you shouldn't just slam them together into a single project, either.

Think about the bad things you get from including your tests into your main code.  You may have name collisions, you may have your unit tests accidentally linked in and shipped with your production executables, and you might do some practices that completely invalidate the legitimacy of your testing, such as statements like  `#ifdef UNIT_TEST` or `if (testing == true) {...}`. If your unit tests aren't testing your actual compiled-and-ready-to-ship production code, they're not helping you prove your code is production ready.

Instead, you should have a strong desire to have the kind of project organization that makes your code easy to understand, easy to test, easy to build, and easy to maintain.  To that end, you should be requiring separate projects that isolate your code, your unit tests, and your production wrapper.

I strongly recommend following doctorlove's advice to implement a larger library project containing all your program's logic, then creating a separate project containing a very thin `main()` function that only calls into your static library where your real logic lies.  Then create a third project containing all your unit tests.  The test project needs to link in your library, plus it also should include its own `main()` in order to execute the tests.

With this structure, one build of your solution should do several things for you.  It would first compile the library, then it would compile and link the unit tests, it would then run your unit tests, and only when they all pass would it then compile and link the production project with your library.   Such an organizational structure makes your code incredibly easy to test (it tests itself with every build!) and very efficient to build (you only build your logic and your tests once), plus it helps all the developers understand where to locate the tests vs. where to locate the code.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you only have a main exe project, you can do some unit testing by creating a new target "UnitTest" for your solution, and set in the properties of the main exe project "Configuration Type" to "Static library (.lib)".

The downside of this methode is that you will have to switch your target incase you wanna build your exe or do some unit testing. So I also suggest @doctorlove's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19357619/20518098).